# Quarkus class auto-generatation mechanism from Avro schemas is not working

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, quarkus, auto-generate

I created a new Kafka Stream project based on Quarkus 2.1.2 following these two guides:

- https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka-streams
- https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka-schema-registry-avro

I put some Avro schemas in the `src/main/avro/` folder and built the project with Maven.
The build is successful but there aren't any Java classes in the `target/generated-sources/avsc` directory.

As said by the guide with the new version of Quarkus

> there’s no need to use a specific Maven plugin to process the Avro schema, this is all done for you!

I also double-checked that the `generate-code` goal was enabled for the `quarkus-maven-plugin`.

Am I missing something or is the guide incomplete in some way? Because it doesn't seems that the class generation is automatically managed by Quarkus.

p.s. I'm using Java 11.0.2 and Maven 3.8.1

Thank you,

Mauro

Comment: Do you have a dependency on `quarkus-avro`?

Comment: If you mean quarkus-apicurio-registry-avro, no, because I use the Confluent Schema Registry, so I added kafka-avro-serializer as dependency.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Ladicek I tried to add the `quarkus-avro` dependency and now I can find the auto-generated classes.

I think that the guide https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka-schema-registry-avro should be modified because the "default" dependency `quarkus-apicurio-registry-avro` has `quarkus-avro` in its dependency while Confluent's `kafka-avro-serializer` doesn't (obviously).

I opened a [issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/19350) to improve the guide.

Thank you very much

Comment: I already submitted a PR to fix the documentation: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/19320

Comment: I linked directly the issue, but you can find it also in the PR created by @Ladicek